# Bootstrap Forms > Input field grid issue > only works when appended

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Noticed something strange on my Bootstrap forms today (v303).

I set my labels to use 3 columns and the input field to use 9 columns, and normally I'd expect this to extend full width of the available space.

But the fields seem to have a mind of their own and are adjusting to their own widths... I can't seem to get them to extend.. even if I add more columns.

What's strange is that, for my fields w/ Bootstrap PREPEND character, it goes full width as expected.

screenshot:
[image]

code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">A</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      **<span class="input-group-addon">@</span>**
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">B</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `input-group` class incorrectly.

> Extend form controls by adding text or buttons before, after, or on both sides of any text-based input. Use `.input-group` with an `.input-group-addon` to prepend or append elements to a single `.form-control`.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

`input-group` will only work well when textbox has other elements before and/or after.  As such, from your second input either remove the enclosing `input-group` div or add some surrounding content within the tag.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">A</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">B</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
</div>
```